# Как запустить приложение с .env файлом в docker контейнере?

Tags: java, maven, docker, .env

Есть приложение, которое должно читать некоторые параметры из .env файла.
Приложение должно запускаться в Docker контейнере.

Для чтения параметров из .env файла использую:

```
Dotenv dotEnv = Dotenv.load();
threadPoolSize = dotEnv.get("SOME_PARAPMETER"));
```

Запускаю docker контейнер:

```
docker create --env-file=.env --name pg_importer --net=host -it pd_importer_docker
docker start -i pg_importer
```

в Docker контейнере выдает:

> Exception in thread "main" io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.DotEnvException:
>   Could not find ./.env on the classpath    at
>   io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.internal.ClasspathHelper.loadFileFromClasspath(ClassPathHelper.kt:37)
>     at
>   io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.internal.DotenvReader.read(DotenvReader.kt:36)
>     at
>   io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.internal.DotenvParser.parse(DotenvParser.kt:26)
>     at io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.DotenvBuilder.load(Dotenv.kt:95)  at
>   io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv$Instance.load(Dotenv.kt:29)     at
>   io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv.load(Dotenv.kt)     at
>   com.ApplicationRun.main(ApplicationRun.java:30)   Suppressed:
>   io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.DotEnvException: Could not find ./.env on
>   the file system (working directory: /project_folder)      at
>   io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.internal.DotenvReader.read(DotenvReader.kt:40)
>         ... 5 more

Как сделать чтобы приложение видело параметры из .env и запускалось в Docker контейнере?

Comment: в этом вашем файле просто переменные окружения записаны? ну так просто передайте их процессу при запуске. в чём сложность-то вы нашли?

Comment: Не совсем понял, при запуске контейнера? $ docker run -e MYVAR1 --env MYVAR2=foo --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash   Нужно читать именно из файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил задачу следующим образом. Для чтения параметров использовал:

```
Dotenv dotEnv = Dotenv.configure().directory("./").ignoreIfMalformed().ignoreIfMissing().load();
```

И запуск проекта с указанием env-file:

```
docker create --env-file=.env --name pg_importer --net=host -it pd_importer_docker
docker start -i pg_importe
```